# Delphi FMX app in iPhone unable to execute

Tags: xcode, delphi, firemonkey

I have Delphi 10.4.2 and I'm trying to test (and execute) an FMX application in my iPhone 13.

I have a MacBook Pro M2, with XCode 13.4.1 installed and I've already tested a Hello World app from my installed XCode to the iPhone. I have an Apple account (haven't paid anything) linked to my XCode. I've read that I do not have to be in the Apple Developer Program (paying 99$) to test applications on a iPhone.

I've already installed the PAServer 21 on my Mac, as well as added the Mac on the Connection Profile Manager and downloaded the SDK adding my iPhoneOS 15.5 SDK.

So, I created an iOs app on XCode, and executed it on my iPhone. That's all good at the moment. Then I went to Delphi and on `Project Options -> Version Info -> CFBundleIdentifier` I added the identifier I created on my original XCode project.

Then, on `Project Options -> Deployment -> Provisioning`, I selected the Provisioning Profile of my XCode app.

The problem is that when I execute the app from Delphi, normally the app installs well, but when I try to execute it (starting the application) it crashes on the iPhone and crashes Delphi as well.

**Edit: Currently Showing these errors**

```
Library not loaded: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python'
  Referenced from: '/Applications/PAServer-21.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lldb/lib/liblldb.3.8.0.dylib'
  Reason: tried: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python' (no such file)
```

Can anybody help or give me some clues about it?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad English .

Comment: "crashes Delphi as well." What *exactly* happens? Are you running the app via the debugger? What error messages are there, if any?

Comment: @DaveNottage I am using "Development" profile on Delphi, so yes, debugging. There aren't any error messages; when the app is installed on the iPhone, you can't use more the interface of Delphi. I have to go to Task Manager and Force the exit.

Comment: So have you tried a release build?

Comment: @XylemFlow just edited with some errors from the PAServer